# Python requests not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to parse search results from this page:
https://entp.hud.gov/idapp/html/condlook.cfm

```
import requests
payload = {
    'fapproval_method':'NEW',
    'fsorted_by':'condo_name',
    'fstate':'WA',
    'fcountry':'',
    'fcondo_id':'',
    'fcondo_name':'',
    'fcity':'',
    'fzip':'',
    'fstatus_code':'A',
    'fsearch_type':'B',
    'fbegin_mo':'',
    'fbegin_dy':'',
    'fbegin_yr':'',
    'fend_mo':'',
    'fend_dy':'',
    'fend_yr':'',
    'came_from':'oth',
    'in_fhac':'true'
}

r = requests.post('https://entp.hud.gov/idapp/html/condlook.cfm', data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

I tried replacing condlook.cfm with condo1.cfm but to no avail. It just returns the same page with values pre-populated and not a results page.

Comment: The form on that page posts to `condo1.cfm`, so you definitely need to honour that. Did you try and get the first form page using a `request.Session()` first to allow the site to set a cookie?

Comment: Yep I did try the Session() command, didn't work, and I think now I know why, as Joseph pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as @MartijnPieters commented, you need to post to `condo1.cfm` since that is where the form posts. Secondly, using a `requests.Session()` allows the first page (`condlook.cfm`) to set the `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` cookies. You must specify the referrer, since apparently `condo1.cfm` has some logic to not return results without the referrer set. Finally, you have a typo in your `payload`: `fcountry` must be `fcounty`.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()

s.get("https://entp.hud.gov/idapp/html/condlook.cfm")

s.headers["Referer"] = "https://entp.hud.gov/idapp/html/condlook.cfm"


payload = {
    'fapproval_method':'NEW',
    'fsorted_by':'condo_name',
    'fstate':'WA',
    'fcounty':'',
    'fcondo_id':'',
    'fcondo_name':'',
    'fcity':'',
    'fzip':'',
    'fstatus_code':'A',
    'fsearch_type':'B',
    'fbegin_mo':'',
    'fbegin_dy':'',
    'fbegin_yr':'',
    'fend_mo':'',
    'fend_dy':'',
    'fend_yr':'',
    'came_from':'oth',
    'in_fhac':'true'
}
r = s.post("https://entp.hud.gov/idapp/html/condo1.cfm", data=payload)
print r.text
```

For what it's worth, I figured this out using Chrome's Network inspector and viewing the HTTP Request headers. I suspected `User-Agent` would be required (some sites look for a 'regular browser') but it turns out in this case the `Referrer` was required.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for spotting my typo. I guess I'll have to become close friends with Chromes Network inspector. I did use it to construct my payload but never spotted the Referer part. Thanks again!